# Last elseif statement does not execute

Tags: matlab, if-statement

My last elseif statement does not execute even if the conditions are met:

Currency_Exchanage != 'Select...' and all other variables (ETF_Exchanage, Index_Exchanage and Stock_Exchanage) = 'Select...'

Here is the section of code that I am concerned about:

```
if (strcmp(ETF_Exchanage,'Select...') == 1) && (strcmp(Stock_Exchanage,'Select...') == 1) && (strcmp(Index_Exchanage,'Select...') == 1)...
        (strcmp(Currency_Exchanage,'Select...') == 1)
    if db == 1 && uni == 1
        tickers = gnr_bloomberg; % Analsise Bloomberg natural resources
        nrm=1;
    elseif db == 1 && uni == 2
        tickers = all_bloomberg; % Analsise Bloomberg all
        nrm=1;
    elseif db == 2 && uni == 1
        tickers = gnr_yahoo;     % Analsise Yahoo natural resources
        nrm=1;
    elseif db == 2 && uni == 2
        tickers = all_yahoo;     % Analsise Yahoo all
        nrm=1;
    end
else
    %Yahoo inputs
    if (strcmp(ETF_Exchanage,'Select...') == 0) && (strcmp(Stock_Exchanage,'Select...') == 1) && (strcmp(Index_Exchanage,'Select...') == 1)...
            (strcmp(Currency_Exchanage,'Select...') == 1); %Choose exhanges from ETF
        tickers = ETF_Yahoo(:,1);
        Exchanges = ETF_Yahoo(:,2);
        Exchange = ETF_Exchanage;
        db=2; %Yahoo Selection

    elseif (strcmp(Index_Exchanage,'Select...') == 0) && (strcmp(Stock_Exchanage,'Select...') == 1) && (strcmp(ETF_Exchanage,'Select...') == 1)...
            (strcmp(Currency_Exchanage,'Select...') == 1); %Choose exhanges from Index
        tickers = Index_Yahoo(:,1);
        Exchanges = Index_Yahoo(:,2);
        Exchange = Index_Exchanage;
        db=2;

    elseif (strcmp(Stock_Exchanage,'Select...') == 0) && (strcmp(ETF_Exchanage,'Select...') == 1) && (strcmp(Index_Exchanage,'Select...') == 1)...
            (strcmp(Currency_Exchanage,'Select...') == 1); %Choose exhanges from Stock
        tickers = Stock_Yahoo(:,1);
        Exchanges = Stock_Yahoo(:,2);
        Exchange = Stock_Exchanage;
        db=2;

    elseif (strcmp(Currency_Exchanage,'Select...') == 0) && (strcmp(Stock_Exchanage,'Select...') == 1) && (strcmp(Index_Exchanage,'Select...') == 1)...
            (strcmp(ETF_Exchanage,'Select...') == 1); %Choose exhanges from Currency
        tickers = Currency_Yahoo(:,1);
        Exchanges = Currency_Yahoo(:,2);
        Exchange = Currency_Exchanage;
        db=2;
    else
        msg = 'Error occurred.\Only one Yahoo input menue must be used!';
        error(msg)
    end
end
```

Any Help would be much appropriated, I can't see where I'm going wrong here. I am using Matlab 2013a.

Comment: in your if clause you use something like  `() && () &&  () ... ()`; This should not work. is there a `&&` or a `||` missing?

Comment: ↑Basically this - when you use `...` to break lines, it runs as if the `...` and linebreak were not there.

Comment: So, the `()` after the `...` is executed as the first statement. This is probably not what it should do.

Comment: Thanks guys! I added in the missing  `&&` and removed the line breaks and it works perfectly now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a breakpoint at the elseif statement in question and then check in the command window what your condition evaluates to.

If it does not evaluate like expected, check what the individual terms evaluate to.

It is important to actually test what the conditions evaluate to in matlab, rather than only visually comparing the string values.

Usually by that point you should get a rough idea what is wrong.

However in your case we can't do these steps for you because something is off. Your code condensed to the more reasonable minimal example

```
if 1 && 1 && 1...
    1;
    disp('I was here')
end
```

does not even execute in R2014a since the interpreter complains about '...' being an unexpected matlab expression.

Comment: I removed the line break  `...` and added an extra  `&&` and now te code works fine. the hew format looks like this:

 `if ww && x && y && z;

         do_something;

  end`